# One Step in Proving the Gamma of $1 \over 2$

Tags: integration

Good Afternoon All.  There is one step in the proof that I never quite understood.

Let $I = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{{-u}^2} du$.  Then
$$I^2 = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{{-u}^2} du \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{{-v}^2} dv$$
Now, if I say that since $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{{-u}^2} du$ is not a function of $v$, I can stack the integral as such
$$I^2 = \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{{-u}^2} du (e^{{-v}^2}) dv \space (*)$$
Then because $e^{{-v}^2}$ is not a function of $u$,
$$I^2 = \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{{-v}^2}e^{{-u}^2} du dv$$
However, to make such a argument in $(*)$, do I need to first know that $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{{-u}^2} du$ converges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you do need to know it converges.  But $\exp (-u^2) \lt  \frac 1{1+u^2}$ for large $u$ is enough to show it.

Comment: Phew, it turns out to be simpler than I thought.  TY!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: if you don't *need* to stick to the rather nice double integral thing, you could use [Euler's Reflection Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) :

$$\Gamma(1-z)\Gamma(z)=\frac\pi{\sin\pi z}\;,\;\;\text{ so}\;\;z=\frac12\implies \Gamma\left(\frac12\right)^2=\frac\pi{\sin\frac\pi2}=\pi\;\ldots\ldots$$

Comment: Thanks dear Don for the comment.